# Open Chrome new tab from outside Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, shortcuts, address-bar

How to open new blank Chrome tab (not window) from outside Chrome when Chrome is already running?

I unsuccessfully tried:

- win + write "chrome". It opens new window with new blank tab
- windows taskbar > address bar > : or / . It opens new window with new blank tab
- Custom Key Manager shorcut to open Chrome. It opens new window with new blank tab

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to open a new tab in an existing Chrome window, but from outside of Chrome?

Comment: @techturtle yes, exactly that :-)

Comment: You can also use a batch file. Put the batch file on your desktop and automatically create a new tab in your Chrome each time you click it.

Comment: @S.Leon I tried the batch file. There is still the same problem. It opens every url succesfully in new tab. But there is no way to open empty new tab in running window. It always opens empty new tab in new window. Does anyone know how to open empty new tab in running window via batch file?

Comment: I think the method provided by techturtle is good. Have you tried it? The batch file can also do that. Maybe the code in the batch file you found is incorrect. I suggest you go to the relevant forum of the batch file for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a script to activate the Chrome window and then open the new tab.  Something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) can do this.  The following is a sample of what that script might look like:

```
#+c::
IfWinExist ahk_exe chrome.exe
{
    WinActivate ahk_exe chrome.exe
    WinWait ahk_exe chrome.exe
    Send ^t
}
```

This script activates if you push <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and will check if Chrome is running, and if it is it will activate the window and send Chrome's hotkey for a new tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).  This doesn't factor in things like if you have more than one Chrome window open, but it should get you started in the right direction.